# Jackson2 PropertyFilter for nested properties, or is there another way?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm currently searching a way to serialize an object in multiple ways without interfering with the classes directly. (like adding lots of annotations)

Imagine a class like this:

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  ...
  User manager;
}
```

The `SimplePropertyFilter` delivers almost the desired functionality but the problem is that this filter ignores the level of the current object and applies all defined filters on each object, whether it is a nested one or not.

I'm not limited to Filters, but I would like to avoid writing multiple classes for each of the desired json response. Is there a way to achieve this behavior with Jackson2 ?

---

If we would like to serialize this for an edit form we need all fields, but for a list of users we probably just need some of them.

For the manager however we always would need "only" the `id` and the `name`. And this is what search a solution for.

The JSON output should become something like this:

```
{
  "id" : "20",
  "login" : "USER20",
  "name" : "User 20",
  "email" : "user20@no.where",
  "manager" : {
     "id" : "1",
     "name" : "Administrator"
  }
}
```

---

I feel like the property filter approach is getting me quite close to the desired solution but from what i found out you can only define "simple" properties.

```
public class UserJsonWriter {
  public String toJson() {
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id", "login", "name", "email", "manager");
    // Unfortunatly I cannot write:
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id", "login", "name", "email", "manager.id", "manager.name");


    User user = userService.getUser(20);
    ObjectMapper copy = objectMapperFactoryBean.getCopy();
    copy.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, CustomFilter.class);
    ObjectWriter writer = copy.writer(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("customFilter", filter));
    return writer.writeValueAsString(user);
  }
}

@JsonFilter("customFilter")
public class CustomFilter {

}
```

And currently the output looks like this.

```
{
  "id" : "20",
  "login" : "USER20",
  "name" : "User 20",
  "email" : "user20@no.where",
  "manager" : {
     "id" : "1",
     "login" : "ADMIN",
     "name" : "Administrator",
     "email" : "admin@no.where",
     "manager" : {
       ... (might continue multiple times)
     }
   }
}
```

---

From what I can tell, the PropertyFilter does not know the current "location" of the serialization, neither does the json generator (directly).

The simplest solution that i can see to be used would look for nested properties during this filtering process. Does this possibility exist in Jackson? Probably there are other libraries that support this behaviour?

EDIT: I also like to add that I'm using Spring MVC, probably there is a way through Spring?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question with YES and a little addon library on github.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter